# Merging software for xaml

Tags: wpf, silverlight, svn, version-control, tfs

For you wpf silverlight people who are working with source control that allows merging.  What is the best software to use for merging?  I am more worried about the xaml then I am the code because this has the potential to change the most during a merge.

ie beyond compare, kdiff etc...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We use Tortoise SVN and subversion; so far I've had no problems merging XAML with the automatic merges they provide.

That said, the fundamental rule is: never trust an automatic merge.

Answer (score 1):

We use SourceGear Vault which works well for us.

They have extracted the merge portion of the software and made it freeware.

[DiffMerge](http://www.sourcegear.com/diffmerge/)